# Adding environment variables to imagedefinitions.json file in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild

When building a docker image with CodeBuild one specifies a imagedefinitions.json file. As I've understood it, it is used to specify the container definition of a task definition.
However, I would like to include environment variables such as in this definition:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
    }]
  }]
}
```

How can I update the imagedefinitions.json file to include this information?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include any other parameter besides container_name and image_uri, as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html).

imagedefinitions.json file is used by CodePipeline in ECS deploy stages to pass both fields to ECS for further task versioning and eventual deployment.

containerDefinitions in the other hand is a property within a task definition [config file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html). That one is from CloudFormation documentation, just for you to check.

Hope it helps.